# Why does my time-related spec fail so often?

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

In my Rails 5 app I regularly run a test suite containing 1000+ tests. Most of the time, they all pass. One test, however, keeps failing from time to time:

```
describe 'DELETE #destroy' do

  context "with valid password" do

    it "sets delete_at" do
      delete :destroy, :params => {:password => @user.password}
      expect(@account.reload.delete_at).to be_within(2.seconds).of(Time.zone.now + DEACTIVATION_TIME)
    end

  end

end
```

The error message is always the same:

```
Failure/Error: expect(@account.reload.delete_at).to be_within(2.seconds).of(Time.zone.now + DEACTIVATION_TIME)
   expected 2018-11-06 09:42:29.000000000 +0100 to be within 2 of 2018-11-06 10:42:29 +0100
```

I presume the error is somehow related to `Timezones` but I have no idea how to fix it. And why does it sometimes pass and sometimes fail?!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this test - use TimeCop instead

Answer (score 0):

`Time.zone.now + DEACTIVATION_TIME` is making your test brittle. If I understand you test correctly, you are interested in checking that a correct `delete_at` value was set on an `account` record. If that's the case, why do you need to add `DEACTIVATION_TIME` to `Time.zone.now`? It's adding a whole hour in the error messages you provided

Comment: `DEACTIVATION_TIME` is a constant from my `_constants.rb`, so I need to use it here in order to keep things DRY. If there's a better way, what would it be?

Comment: I understand it is a constant, and I understand you want to use it in your tests to keep it DRY, but how are you using it in your implementation? What value does it hold?